# Watson: Dialogs. Are they required?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

We are working on a micro-service that interacts with Watson.

I was presented with the following argument: "There is no need to use dialogs in a Conversation project on Watson. Declaring the intents and entities is just enough to get the work done"

Based on the documentation, I have the impression that using dialogs is a requirement in order to train Watson correctly on how to interpret the combination of intents and entities. Plus, in the Dialog section, you have the chat that allows you to make corrections.

Is there a way that I can confirm that Dialogs are or are not a requirement?

Answer (score 5):

If you plan to just use intents and entities programmatically then you don’t need dialog.

You will need to create one blank dialog, with a condition of `true`. This is to avoid SPEL errors relating to no node found.

From a programming point of view (and ignoring conversation for a minute), if you need to take action on intents, entities, or change context variables. The recommendation is to do that in dialog. This way your code is not split across two systems, making it easier to maintain.

Comment: Hi! Your answer shows one new point of view. I really did don't know about this possibility at least saw your answer. Thank u

Answer (score 2):

***Probably*** in this phrase above, the author wants to say that you only need to create #intents and @entities for your Conversation and defining the purpose for your bot, this is true, depends on what you want to do in your bot, cause after it you can just create your dialog flow!

The Dialog section is for you create your Dialog flow, is absolutely needed when you want to create one conversation flow, e.g: one chatbot.

A workspace contains the following types of *artifacts*:

> **[Intents](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/intents.html)**: An intent represents the purpose of a user's input, such as a
>   question about business locations or a bill payment. You define an
>   intent for each type of user request you want your application to
>   support. In the tool, the name of an intent is always prefixed with
>   the # character. To train the workspace to recognize your intents, you
>   supply lots of examples of user input and indicate which intents they
>   map to.
>
> **[Entities](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html)**; An entity represents a term or object that is relevant to
>   your intents and that provides a specific context for an intent. For
>   example, an entity might represent a city where the user wants to find
>   a business location, or the amount of a bill payment. In the tool, the
>   name of an entity is always prefixed with the @ character. To train
>   the workspace to recognize your entities, you list the possible values
>   for each entity and synonyms that users might enter.
>
> **[Dialog](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html)**: A dialog is a branching conversation flow that defines how
>   your application responds when it recognizes the defined intents and
>   entities. You use the dialog builder in the tool to create
>   conversations with users, providing responses based on the intents and
>   entities that you recognize in their input.

**EDIT:**

Likes @Simon O'Doherty said, if your purpose is to just use the Intents and Entities programmatically, then you don't need the Dialog. His answer is complete.

- See the documentation for [Building a Dialog](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#dialog-build).

Answer (score 2):

Yes Intents and Entities may seem to be just enough for you, and you can generate the answer - programmatically - based on them. But you should keep in mind that **Dialog** *does* **not** mean **Response**. *I know it's hard to find this clearly in Watson documentation*.

If you need to get access to **context** variables in the next node or dialog, you should define them in **slots**. Without defining dialogs for each intent, context variables will not be accessible or conveyed in the next dialog.

Comment: I find out that you don't need the dialog part of Watson.

Answer (score 1):

You need Dialog portion of Watson Conversation service if you want to respond to the user queries.

The Intents and entities are the understanding piece, and the Dialog portion is the response side of the conversation.